Connecting to host from container using Podman on Windows
On my Windows 11 machine, I have a website running on port 5213.
I want to be able to reach this endpoint from a container running in Podman.
Looking at similar questions I tried the following approach, running this from the windows terminal:
podman run --rm -it alpine sh
apk add curl
curl host.containers.internal:5213

But the result is this:
curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.containers.internal port 5213 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I've tried allowing port 5213 in the windows firewall, and even turning off the firewall completely, but no luck.
I also just updated Podman, and when setting up the "Podman machine", I enabled the --user-mode-networking flag.
What am I missing here?
